# Create a feature receiver that adds the calendar webpart to the homepage?

Tags: web-part, calendar

I need to put the webpart calendar in a specific SharePoint 2010 site, but we need to do it by code.

The calendar must be shown on the main zone.  How can I add the web-part with C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) to do this. [There is](http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.com/2010/10/add-web-part-to-page-using-c-code-in.html) an example how to add Content Editor web part to the page, but in your case it should work too. If you works with published page you can use this code.

```
gWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(webSite);
SPListItem item = publishingWeb.PagesList.GetItemByFileName(pageName);
if (item != null)
{
    PublishingPage publishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(item);
    try
    {
        if (item.File.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None)
        {
            publishingPage.CheckOut();                     
        }                  
        else
        {
            item.File.UndoCheckOut();
            publishingPage.CheckOut();
        }

        webPartManger = item.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

        //code that adds web part

        publishingPage.Update();
        publishingPage.CheckIn(updateComment);

        if (publishingWeb.PagesList.EnableModeration)
        {
            item.File.Publish(updateComment);
            item.File.Approve(updateComment);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (webPartManager != null)
        {
            webPartManager.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```